# Как в flask узнать авторизирован ли юзер и если нет напрвить его в login

Tags: python, flask

Как в flask узнать авторизирован ли юзер и если нет напрвить его в login

код:

```
class User(db.Model,UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(128), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255), primary_key=True, nullable=False)

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    user = request.form.get('user')
    password = request.form.get('password')
    if login and password:
        userlog = User.query.filter_by(login=login).first()
        if user and check_password_hash(userlog.password, password):
            login_user(userlog)
            redirect(url_for['myprogrece'])
        else:
            flash('Login or passwort incorect')
    else:
        flash('Please fill')
    return render_template('login.html')
```

Comment: Зависит от того, как именно сделаны юзеры у вас.

Comment: добавил код юзера

Comment: А код авторизации?

Comment: доавил код логина

Comment: Что такое `login_user`?

Comment: это залогинить пользователя

Comment: Это ни о чём не говорит. Код авторизации неполный, вы не показали функцию `login_user`, и без неё ответить на ваш вопрос не получится

Comment: это стандартная функция в flask

Comment: В flask не существует функции login_user, вы что-то напутали

Comment: https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: flask-login это не flask, а стороннее расширение. Ну и раз уж вы дали ссылку на документацию, то вы в ней можете прочитать, что получить информацию о текущем пользователе в этом расширении можно через объект `flask_login.current_user`

Comment: И соответственно `current_user.is_authenticated` будет `True`, если пользователь авторизован

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо использовать @login_required

В конце добавьте такой код(Для указания ссылки куда попадёт пользователь в случае если он не авторизован):

```
@application.after_request
def redirect_to_sign(response):
    if response.status_code == 401:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
        
    return response
```

После этого используйте @login_required
Пример:

```
@app.route('/admin')
@login_required
   def admin():
      return '<h1>Admin page</h1>'
```